# css background image completion

Tags: css, centering

Please take a look at the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UrLQ2/

```
<div class="header">
    header
</div>
<div class="navi_wrap">
    <div class="navi">
        <a href='#'>Tab1</a>
        <a href='#'>Tab2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    content
</div>
```

The background image should have 100% width, header and content should be centered.

I'm trying to achieve the missing orange background block left to the navigation block.

What's the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `margin:0px auto;` from `div.navi` and `div.wrapper`

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rikuneho/2/)**

Comment: You can use `text-align: center` for that or add bg image to the parent div